# Force showing Shopping Cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have the theme WP Rentals and it has his own shopping cart in the top menu, but i need to use the merchant payments included in the theme and not the one of woocommerce, when i disable the woocommerce payments the cart disappears! So,i need that shopping cart for other woocommerce purposes, here is the code statement, when i remove the "if" estatement it is still not showing up.

```
                    global $wpestate_global_payments;
                    if(  class_exists( 'WooCommerce' ) ){
                        $wpestate_global_payments->show_cart_icon_mobile();
                    }
                   ?>
```

Comment: Are you disabling the whole Woocommerce plugin?

Comment: Nop, I'll tell you about the issue if it has its own payment system for booking, I want to use that theme for its same booking system but I have woocommerce enabled for a section of products, so that bookings do not appear as products I use separate methods, all good until then but when I disable the "woocommerce" option in the booking theme, the cart is removed, which is very useful for my products.